# Splitting an iterator in two succeeding iterators in python

Tags: python, iterator

I have an iterator that yields a dictionary with several data fields. Is there a way to split this stream of data into two following iterators that each feature only a certain data field of the preceding streamed dictionary?

```
class Splitter(IteratorBase):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        super().__init__(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        for pt in self.iterable:
            yield pt["field1"], pt["field2"]
```

does not work, because this just yields tuples with both fields

Comment: I had no issue running your code after removing `BaseIterator`, changing in `__init__` to have `self.iterable = iterable`, and giving data as `[{"field1": 1, "field2": 2}, {"field1": 3, "field2": 4}]`. A simple `foo = Splitter(data)` and `for a, b in foo:` works fine.

Comment: @FelipeFaria This code produces a single iterator of tuples, not a pair of separate iterators. (Which, to be fair, isn't that much different from what `itertools.tee` does, though the tuple iterator is only accessible between the `tee` iterators.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```py
import itertools

# Make iterator for some data
data = [{'field1': 1, 'field2': 2}, {'field1': 3, 'field2': 4}]
it = iter(data)
# Make two iterators out of the first one
it1, it2 = itertools.tee(it)
# Use first iterator for field1
it1 = (elem['field1'] for elem in it1)
# Use second iterator for field2
it2 = (elem['field2'] for elem in it2)
# Print elements of each iterator
print(*it1)
# 1 3
print(*it2)
# 2 4
```

Comment: Confusing to reuse variable names like that.

Comment: thanks, but will this traverse the data collection twice or just once? I am asking because of efficacy

Comment: One traversal, but elements pulled by one iterator have to be cached in memory until the other iterator uses it as well.

Comment: @CD86 The iterator is traversed just once (note this works for any iterator, and many cannot be traversed twice). Internally, `tee` reads elements as they are needed and stores them in an internal queue until all iterators have gone through it (see explanation in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)).

Comment: I forgot to mention that the following code expects the resulting iterators to be of type or subclass of IteratorBase

Comment: What is `IteratorBase`, and how does one instantiate it? Is it just a wrapper around an iterator, or an ABC that represents an iterator, or...?

Comment: it is a dataflow object https://github.com/tensorpack/dataflow